# Why do we beg on simchas torah when we are supposed to be happy?

Tags: tefilla, simchah-joy-happiness, simchat-torah

I was bothered by the fact that on Simchas Torah, when we are supposed to be happy and rejoice with the Torah, we are busy with prayers like אנא ה' הושיעה נא etc.

What place do these prayers, which are not happy ones per se, have in our merriment?

Comment: is this different from saying Hallel on any Yom Tov?

Comment: @rosends I think many understand the אנא השםs in hallel to be praise not request. I think the OP is referring to the אנא השםs in the hakafos.

Comment: @robev I understand that, but in terms of what we say, we say hoshanos which make the same request (and much more) all during Sukkot (z'man simchateinu) and say Hallel which includes that request/pleading in the midst of praise even though v'samachta b'chagecha.

Comment: The better question would be: What do the אנא phrases have to do with "Simchas Torah"?  (I.e. Simchas Torah itself was originally the day we begged for rain, so it makes sense to say things like אנא - but how did they get intermingled with the Merry Hakafot?)

Comment: I think the answer to your question lies in the fact that we say hakafot on Simchat Torah. That's a much later custom as was the concept of Simchat Torah, itself. My point is, that I think Mas. Succah mentions that hakafot around the mizbe'ach were done daily during Succot, and while doing it, they said the phrase *Ana Hashem*, etc.

Comment: @DannySchoemann See ^^. I think you may be able to compile an answer from this. I don't have access to all the sources, now.

Comment: CC @rosends See ^^.

Comment: @DanF - I do not recall the Mishna mentioning Hakafot in the Bet Hamikdash on the 8th day.

Comment: @DannySchoemann not the 8th day. During the rest of Succot. The question for research is multi-fold. 1) Why did Shemini Atzeret "become" Simchat Torah (I'm assuming Israel) and 2) Why hakafot were added? I.e. the main question is not exactly as OP implied that "Ana Hashem" is said on Simchat Torah. It is intrinsically part of hakafot, apparently.